# Unreachable statement (14:9)

Tags: apex

I've this class

```
public with sharing class CreateContact {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    // Method to get Account Name. 
    public static string getAccountName(String recordId) {
        Account objAccount = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :recordId];
        System.debug(objAccount);
        return objAccount.Name;
    }
    // Method to Save data.
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static string saveData(String firstName, String lastName) {
        System.debug(' ' +firstName+ ' ' + lastName);
        return (' ' +firstName+ ' ' + lastName);
        insertContact(firstName, lastName); //error on this line.
    }
    // Method to insert Contacts
    private static void insertContact(String firstName, String lastName) {
        Contact c = new Contact(
            FirstName = firstName,
            LastName = lastName
        );
        insert c;
        System.debug('Contact added is: '+firstName+lastName);
    }
}
```

Getting error on line #14:9

Any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you researched when running into this error? Have you looked at what the "[unreachable statement](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unreachable-code-error-in-java/)" error message is trying to tell you?

Comment: Yes I did, and I got the answer to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fixed the error, I wrote the calling method below return statement so it is unable to reach insertContact()

```
public with sharing class CreateContact {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    // Method to get Account Name. 
    public static string getAccountName(String recordId) {
        Account objAccount = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :recordId];
        System.debug(objAccount);
        return objAccount.Name;
    }
    // Method to Save data.
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static string saveData(String firstName, String lastName) {
        System.debug(' ' +firstName+ ' ' + lastName);
        insertContact(firstName, lastName);
        return (' ' +firstName+ ' ' + lastName);
    }
    // Method to insert Contacts
    private static void insertContact(String firstName, String lastName) {
        Contact c = new Contact(
            FirstName = firstName,
            LastName = lastName
        );
        insert c;
        System.debug('Contact added is: '+firstName+lastName);
    }
}
```